# Permutations of MULTIPLE

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of distinct rearrangements of the word "MULTIPLE" that can be made preserving the order in which the vowels (U,I,E) occur is what?

The answer given is $$\frac{8!}{(2!)6}$$ i dont get how they come to this answer

Answer (score 3):

Out of $8$ positions, select $3$ positions for $U,I,E$ in $\binom83$ ways. $U,I,E$ will not permute but the remaining $5$ letters permute in $\displaystyle\frac{5!}{2!}$ ways, because $L$ repeats. The total permutations are $\displaystyle\binom83\cdot\frac{5!}{2!}=\frac{8!}{2!3!}$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $8!$ possibilities if the two letters $L$ are taken to be distinct and no conditions are posed.

So there are $\frac{8!}{2!}$ possibilities if the two letters $L$ are not taken to be distinct. The double counting is repaired by dividing by $2$.

There are not $3!=6$ orderings but only one ordering for the vowels (since the order is fixed).

Also this must be repaired, this time by dividing by $3!=6$.

Final result: $$\frac{8!}{2!3!}=\frac{8!}{2\cdot6}$$